# can we pass GCP(google cloud platform) service account credentials as key value pairs, without using the credential file?

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, service-accounts, aws-secrets-manager

In GCP, can we fetch service account keys from the AWS secrets manager as key-value pairs instead of passing them as a credential file? I'm trying to use the credentials in packer/Jenkins via fetching it from the AWS secret manager. please let me know it will be very helpful.

Comment: How will you load the credential after? I don't  understand the use case and how you will une the secret data after.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I'm using the service account credentials in packer and Jenkins, I need to secure my credentials for which I'm using AWS secrets manager, but the problem is the credentials of the service account that I'm using are in a JSON file, but I want to fetch it using AWS secrets manager which is not a file.

Comment: Encode the contents of the service account JSON file as base64. Import the base64 data into Secrets Manager as K/V. Base64 decode on retrieval into memory. The Google SDK APIs support reading credentials from memory / in-memory data stream.

Comment: If you can't paste the JSON content as a string, encode it in b64 as proposed by @JohnHanley. With the client libraries, in most of the language, you can create your credential from JSON -> Decode your b64 secret content and directly provide tht JSON content to the library